# Erro: Valor não pode ser nulo. Nome do parâmetro: dataTable. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta no banco e exibi-la em um `datagrid`, não tenho tanta experiencia, faço curso técnico e é minha primeira pergunta aqui, o código que estou utilizando é este:

```
Public Sub PreencheDataGrid(ByRef x As DataGridView, ByVal op1 As Integer, ByVal op2 As Integer)
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

    conectaBanco()

    Dim query As String

    query = "SELECT * FROM vw_tb_clientes"

    objcmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    SDA.SelectCommand = objcmd
    SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
    bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet

    'Deixa o DataGridView limpo
    x.DataSource = Nothing

    x.DataSource = bSource
    SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

    fechaBanco()
End Sub
```

Pelo que entendi com o meu *debug*, o erro está no código `SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)`, mas não sei o que está ocorrendo já que tenho outro `datagridview` com quase o mesmo código e funcional, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou especificar a tabela em seu `DataSet`.
Veja as implementações abaixo para corrigir o problema:

```
Public Sub PreencheDataGrid(ByRef x As DataGridView, ByVal op1 As Integer, ByVal op2 As Integer)
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

    conectaBanco()

    Dim query As String

    query = "SELECT * FROM vw_tb_clientes"

    objcmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    SDA.SelectCommand = objcmd

    'Declarei aqui para mostrar o uso do parâmetro
    Dim dbDataSetAs New DataSet("Tab") 'Tab será o nome do nosso dataset e da nossa tabela
    '---
    SDA.Fill(dbDataSet, "Tab") 'Preenche os dados na Tab
    bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
    bSource.DataMember = "Tab" 'Indica que é para puxar da Tab os dados

    'Deixa o DataGridView limpo
    x.DataSource = Nothing

    x.DataSource = bSource
    SDA.Update(dbDataSet, "Tab")

    fechaBanco()
End Sub
```

Comment: Esqueci de colocar as criações de variáveis, estão fora do sub: 
Public objcmd As MySqlCommand
Public dbDataSet As DataTable


Ou seja, dbDataSet é um DataTable

Comment: Se for utilizar o `DataTable`, então faltou o `New`. Observe que no meu exemplo, com o `DataSet` também precisa.

Comment: Agora aconteceu outra coisa, está colocando normalmente no datagridview, mas as colunas "Nome Empresarial" e "Nome Fantasia" estão trazendo todos as linhas com o conteúdo do título da coluna, estou usando o mesmo código para filtrar só muda a query, que quando filtra por nome fica assim:


**query = "SELECT 'Nome Empresarial', 'Nome Fantasia', UF, Municipio, Bairro, Logradouro, Complemento, CEP, Filial FROM vw_tb_clientes"**

Comment: Se você usar aspas, vai "criar" uma coluna com o valor entre aspas. Primeiro coloque o nome da coluna, depois a descrição.

Comment: `SELECT nome_empresarial 'Nome Empresarial', nome_fantasia 'Nome Fantasia', UF, Municipio, Bairro, Logradouro, Complemento, CEP, Filial FROM vw_tb_clientes`

Comment: isso eu teria que modificar na view?

Comment: Deu certo @MatheusMenegatte?

Comment: Agora deu certo, muito obrigado.